# Days since class one was last seen Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have pandas dataframe and I want to calculate number of days since class 1 was last seen per group and add it as a column to the dataframe. How can I do it?

The code below gives dummy data:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = [datetime.today() + timedelta(delta) for delta in range(20)]
dates = [datetime.strftime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')[:10] for date in dates]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.repeat(dates,2),
          'group':['a', 'b']*20,
           'class': np.random.choice([0,1], 40)})  
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
last_seen = (df['date'].where(df['class']==1)
                       .groupby(df['group'])
                       .ffill()
                              )
df['day_passed'] = df['date'] - last_seen
```

Output (data generated with `np.random.seed(1)`):

```
         date group  class day_passed
0  2020-03-17     a      1     0 days
1  2020-03-17     b      1     0 days
2  2020-03-18     a      0     1 days
3  2020-03-18     b      0     1 days
4  2020-03-19     a      1     0 days
5  2020-03-19     b      1     0 days
6  2020-03-20     a      1     0 days
7  2020-03-20     b      1     0 days
8  2020-03-21     a      1     0 days
9  2020-03-21     b      0     1 days
```

Comment: when the class is 1, can you make days since last_class1 (difference with the last date) rather than 0?

Comment: @FissehaBerhane wouldn’t that mean you just take whatever the above output and add 1 day?